# VB.NET Application Unable to Execute SSIS Package, gets COM Error

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am having a problem with a VB.NET application which is trying to execute an SSIS package.  I have a DB server and an app server.  Both in the same domain, each fully visible to the other, network wise.  DB is running SQL2008 R2, app has SSIS 2008 R2 installed.  Both servers have had SQL2008 R2 SP1 applied.

My app (which runs on my developmet box, naturally) includes an SSIS package which is included as a .dtsx file in the same folder as the executable.  At run time the package is loaded and executed using a connection string that is passed in as a parameter.  I have verified this connection string beyond all reasonable doubt.

The error is as follows:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E80FE1DB-D1AA-4D6B-BA7E-040D424A925C} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Both the DB and the app server have Client Connectivity and Backwards Compatibility Tools installed.  Some of my research suggested running REGSVR32 on the DTS.DLL file found in the \binn folder.  Successfully registered the file, but it id not change the results.

I'm really stumped on this one.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework is your VB.NET application running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the application had been compiled with a reference to the SQL2005 ManagedDTS.dll and was being deployed to a SQL 2008 environment.  The class IDs are different.  If you are having this issue in a .NET application, check the references and confirm that your reference to the ManagedDTS.DLL is using the version of the DLL that matches your production environment.

Comment: In case anyone thinks I'm attempting to artificially generate reputation, I did some research on the etiquette of answering my own question, and found that it is acceptable:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17851